# National censuses in the Diaspora

Tags: halacha, golus-exile, census

Shalom.

It is census time in my country (the U.K.).

I have been wondering how Jews have historically dealt with these requests on the part of foreign governments. Obviously the members of one’s household must be counted to give the appropriate data. I haven’t been able to find any information about Jews being prosecuted for not participating in these things, so my question is: how has participation in national censuses in the diaspora been justified over the years?

The problem as I see it: The head of a Jewish household must usually put a definite number of Jews on the census form, thus ‘counting’ in some sense. I have read about some justifiable reasons for counting Jews here: https://www.cjnews.com/featured/jewish-learning/counting-on-jews-what-to-do-when-the-census-form-lands-in-your-mailbox
But can’t see how these reasons would apply in a foreign, especially a hostile, land.

Many thanks for your time.

P.S. I am a Gentile hoping to convert so am looking to the future in asking this question!